# Push values of clicked buttons into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to push the values of the clicked buttons into a JS array named `values`. After that I want to check the length of of this array and if it has the length of 6 the condition is true. The problem with this code is that I get no alert.

**JS**

```
var values = [];

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.ui-btn').click(function() {
        values.push($(this).val());             
    });
});
if (values.length == 6) {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <button name="btn1" type="submit" id="btn1" value="1" class="ui-btn"></button>
    <button name="btn2" type="submit" id="btn2" value="2" class="ui-btn"></button>
</div> // I have up to 9 buttons, thats only a piece
```

Comment: i would check that the php variable is been parsed by JS properly it may thing is a string, also if the php echoes a js array you aren't checking for the length of the right hand side array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is put the `if` statement inside the `click()` jQuery event handler, like so:

```
$('.ui-btn').click(function() {
    values.push($(this).val());
    if (values.length == 6) {
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
     }
});
```

See working example at [JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/oew7jzc4/2/).

---

The problem with your code is that the `if` statement is only executed once, at the beginning, to check if the length of the array is 6. It needs to be run *every time* a button is clicked (therefore inside the `click` handler).

Comment: Yes thank you it works. I will accept your answer in 5 minutes. :)

Comment: @klamertd I'm glad I helped!